# Existence of threshold function for increasing property

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

I am unsure of an argument in the proof of the existence of a threshold function for increasing properties.
For completeness, a threshold function for a random graph is a function p*(n) s.t.
$$
lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{G}_{n,p}\in \mathcal{P}) = 
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } p/p* \to 0 \\
1 \text{ if } p/p* \to \infty
\end{cases}
$$
And increasing property just means that $\mathcal{P}$ is a collection of subsets of all edges of a graph and if $A \in \mathcal{P}$ then every superset of A must also be an element of $\mathcal{P}$.
I have seen that one can define p*(n) as $\mathbb{P}_{n,p*(1/2)}=1/2$ and this p* is then a threshold function for $\mathcal{P}$.
Now my question is, is the **choice of 1/2 crucial**? Maybe I have overseen something in the proofs (everyone I have looked for uses 1/2) but I don't get why it is important because for the asymptotics argument every $0 < \epsilon < 1$ would be appropriate.
To not rewrite the hole proof, here is one of the references I consulted https://www.math.kit.edu/iag6/lehre/semprobmeth2020s/media/topics-in-random-graphs.pdf.

Comment: It is indeed not crucial, it just makes more sense to write 1/2 if you have to pick an arbitrary real in (0,1) so I guess that's why everybody uses it